# How to extend maven packaging type? Is there some additional plugin packaging step that I'm missing?

Tags: java, plugins, maven-3, packaging

I've been trying to get a zip-maven-plugin that I created to work for over a week. There are numerous examples, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Some of the examples that I've been looking at are:

- http://softwaredistilled.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-create-custom-maven-packaging.html
- http://maestrodev.github.io/zip-bundle-maven-plugin/usage.html
- Plus many more...

The examples that I've found in my search seem to only indicate that a component.xml file is needed for the extension and that in the project where it is used adding an `<extensions>true</extensions>` attribute to the plugin reference.

I've created the following components.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/

```
<component-set>
  <components>
    <!--
     | ZIP 
     |-->
    <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler</role>
      <role-hint>zip</role-hint>
      <implementation> 
          org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler                    
      </implementation>
      <configuration>
          <type>zip</type>
          <includesDependencies>true</includesDependencies>
          <addedToClasspath>false</addedToClasspath>
      </configuration>
    </component>
    <component>
        <role>
            org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping
        </role>
        <role-hint>zip</role-hint>
        <implementation>
            org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping
        </implementation>
        <configuration>
            <lifecycles>
                <lifecycle>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <phases>
                      <package>
                        org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single
                      </package>
                      <install>
                        org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install
                      </install>
                      <deploy>
                        org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
                      </deploy>
                    </phases>
                </lifecycle>
            </lifecycles>
        </configuration>
    </component>    
  </components>
</component-set>
<component-set>
```

org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler
      zip
      
          org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler
      
      
        zip
        true
        false
      
    
    
         org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping
         zip
         
            org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping
         
         
            
                 
                     default
                     
                         
                             org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single
                         
                         
                             org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install
                         
                          
                               org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy

And a plugin's pom.xml file that looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.devops.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>zip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <name>zip-maven-plugin Maven Plugin</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>zip</goalPrefix>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                        true
                    </skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've added the plugin in the target pom.xml like this:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>my-zipped-artifact</artifactId>    
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>zip</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.devops.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

By turning on Maven's debugging mode using the -X flag, I find this output:

```
[DEBUG] Created new class realm extension>com.mycompany.devops.maven.plugins:zip-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm extension>com.mycompany.devops.maven.plugins:zip-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm extension>com.mycompany.devops.maven.plugins:zip-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   Included: com.mycompany.devops.maven.plugins:zip-maven-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project mycompany:myartifact:zip:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: [ClassRealm[extension>com.mycompany.devops.maven.plugins:zip-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993]]
[DEBUG] Created new class realm project>mycompany:myartifact:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Populating class realm project>mycompany:myartifact:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging zip from ClassRealm[project>mycompany:myartifact:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: zip @ line 12, column 16
```

Maven is attempting to process my plugin, but doesn't find it later. Any ideas?

Comment: @kvorobiev, thanks for the edit!